# Can we response an Any type on gRPC?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm building a server to support a 3rd party app. The server is required to have only one path but will respond different types of output based on their provided actions. The issue occurs when sometimes the response is an array but in other cases, they are objects (I need a mix of message and stream in short). Does anyone know how to satisfy this logic? Please help. Thank you

I currently have this logic in my .proto but obviously, it doesn't work.

```
rpc CustomHandler(CustomActionRequest) returns (Any) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/custom"
      body: "*"
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

- re the message vs array problem: rather than sending an array, consider sending a message that *has* an array
- in general, consider `oneof` over `Any`, as that more appropriately declares and restricts what the expected / permitted data is

Comment: Thank you for the advice. But in this case, I need a mix between message and stream since I can't change the requirement on the 3rd party app. Is there any case I can apply this logic?

Comment: @phuwn do you mean "stream" in the gRPC sense? for that, you'd need to always return a stream, just: in some/many cases it would be a stream of exactly one message

Comment: This is mind-blowing. But also I get back a weird text instead of an array.

```json
{"result":{"test":"2"}}{"result":{"test":"1"}}
```